# Update state array in React JS with item from Smart Contract

Tags: javascript, reactjs, smartcontracts

I have a state array in react which I am trying to add items from a smart contract

The state array is initialised as

const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

1. and 2. below did not work, but 3. does work when the array is set outside the loop

What am I doing wrong in 1. and 2?

——————————————————————

1. did not work

```
  for (var i = 1; i <= productCount; i++) {
        const product = await marketplace.methods.products(i).call()
        setProducts({
          products: [...this.state.products, product]
        })
      }
```

——————————————————————

2. did not work

```
  for (var i = 1; i <= productCount; i++) {
        const product = await marketplace.methods.products(i).call()
         setProducts(prevState => ({
            products: [...prevState.products, product]
         }))
      }
```

——————————————————————

3. worked

```
  let productArray =[]
  for (var i = 1; i <= productCount; i++) {
        const product = await marketplace.methods.products(i).call()
        productArray.push[product]
      }
  setProduct(productArray)
```

——————————————————————

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a functional component, not a class component, so you shouldn't be using `this` or `this.state` - that's why (1) doesn't work.

(2) doesn't work because your initial products are a *plain array* - it's not an object with a `products` property:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
```

so

```
     setProducts(prevState => ({
        products: [...prevState.products, product]
     }))
```

doesn't make sense - `prevState` is an array, not an object with a `products` property.

With a small tweak, (2) could be made to work:

```
     setProducts(prevState => ([...prevState, product]));
```

There's also almost certainly no need to use `.call`, and you can speed up the process by using `Promise.all` instead of waiting for each function to finish individually:

```
Promise.all(
  Array.from(
    { length: productCount },
    (_, i) => marketplace.methods.products(i + 1)()
  )
)
  .then((newProducts) => {
    setProducts([...products, ...newProducts]);
  })
  // .catch(handleErrors);
```

That's the version I'd prefer, if your code permits you to make all the requests at once.

Comment: went crazy looking for the checkbox, it's a tick on my machine, but thanks again

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 disobey the one of the basic rules of hooks in React.

`Only Call Hooks at the Top Level`. i.e. You should avoid calling hooks in loops, nested functions or conditionals.

As already stated also, there is no reason for the use of `this` in the first approach considering the fact that you're using a React hook.

Read more about Hooks Rules on the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).